# How to prove that $(T^2-I)(T-3I) =0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be the linear operator on $R^3$ defined by
>   $T(x,y,z)=(3x,x-y,2x+y+z).$, prove that$(T^2-I)(T-3I)=o.$

I am having trouble understanding this notation:
What I did was:
$(T^2-I)(T-3I)=[T(3x,x-y,2x+y+z)-(x,y,z)][(3x,x-y,2x+y+z)-(3x,3y,3z)]=[(9x,2x+y,9x+z)-(x,y,z)](0,x-4y,2x+y-2z)=(8x,2x,9x)(0,x-4y,2x+y-2z)\neq0$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are writing composition as  a product. You cannot multiply two vectors so the answer you arrived at does not even make sense.

Comment: Some notation explanation? You have two operator expressions side bt side.  Is this to be a dot product of the two terms or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T$ is a linear operator, it can be written as a 3x3 matrix. Then a call to $T$ is equivalent to matrix multiplication, so that
$$T(x,\,y,\,z)=T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$
From the given definition, we find that
$$T=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\1&-1&0\\2&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$I$ is the 3x3 identity matrix. This gives
$$(T^2-I)(T-3I)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
The intermediate steps are left for the reader to verify.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Calculate the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

T as a matrix has the rows

```
3 0 0
1 -1 0
2 1 1
```

$(T^2−I)(T−3I)$ means compute with T as a matrix